# How to update a MySQL table with fresh data currently in Excel?

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

It was easy using phpMyAdmin to pull a list of WordPress admin comments that were missing an IP location, but now that I've got that data in hand I'm looking for a quick way to insert it into the table. My guess is that'll probably be the use (upload) of a .sql file.

» [WordPress ERD](http://codex.wordpress.org/images/9/9e/WP3.0-ERD.png)

I've currently got my fresh data in an Excel sheet, with columns for comment_ID and comment_author_IP. There are several hundred records, with a variety of IP addresses.

**UPDATE:**

The winning query:

```
UPDATE wp_comments x, temp xx
SET x.comment_author_IP = xx.IP
WHERE x.comment_ID = xx.ID;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are looking into a manual and easy process

- Use phpMyAdmin to upload your Excel to a new table. (it can import Excels too);
- add some indexes on foreign keys on the new created table;
- then join the new table with the actual table and update the relevant fields.

Comment: Good thinking. Probably wouldn't even need to join the tables, right? Simply using WHERE on the comment_ID for matching during the UPDATE query.

Comment: Found a quick way to do an INNER JOIN during the update query. Thanks for the suggestion to import the xls file!